# ACPID not able to run commands in scripts

Tags: linux, bash, script, acpi

I have an HP Elitebook 2740p that has the old style rotating monitor for tabletmode. This rotation generates an ACPI event which I am using to run a script that rotates the screen as well as the touch and pen input when the monitor is rotated into and out of tabletmode. When using ACPID, Xrandr, Xinput, and Krita commands do not execute, but logging shows that the script executed. The screen and pen/touch inputs do not rotate and no errors are logged.   However, when running the scripts manually as root or as user, they execute as intended and rotate the screen, touch, and pen inputs. DISPLAY variable is not set in the scripts

The scripts are as follows

/etc/acpi/events/tabletmode

```
event=video/tabletmode.*
action=/etc/acpi/actions/tabletmode.sh
```

/etc/acpi/actions/tabletmode.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
logger "tabletmode.sh executed"
grep -q 0 /sys/devices/platform/hp-wmi/tablet
if [ $? = 0 ]
then
    /home/foo/scripts/tabletmodeoff ;
else
    /home/foo/scripts/tabletmodeon ;
fi
```

/home/foo/scripts/tabletmodeoff

```
#!/bin/sh
source /home/foo/.Xdbus
/usr/bin/xrandr -o normal
/usr/bin/xinput set-prop "Wacom Serial Penabled 2FG Touchscreen Pen Pen (0)" 144 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1
/usr/bin/xinput set-prop "Wacom Serial Penabled 2FG Touchscreen Finger" 144  1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1
```

/home/foo/scripts/tabletmodeon

```
#!/bin/sh
source /home/foo/.Xdbus
/usr/bin/xrandr -o inverted
/usr/bin/xinput set-prop "Wacom Serial Penabled 2FG Touchscreen Pen Pen (0)" 144 -1 0 1 0 -1 1 0 0 1
/usr/bin/xinput set-prop "Wacom Serial Penabled 2FG Touchscreen Finger" 144 -1 0 1 0 -1 1 0 0 1
su -c /usr/bin/krita foo
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean  by “certain commands will not run”?

Comment: The xrandr, xinput, and Krita commands do not execute.

Comment: (1) What’s your basis for saying that?  Are you getting error messages?  (If so, what are they?)  Or are you just observing what functionality doesn’t occur?  (2) Is DISPLAY set for your event-driven scripts?  Do your scripts work correctly when run interactively / manually if you unset DISPLAY?  … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … …  Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: updated the question but I did some testing based on your DISPLAY variable questions and was able to resolve it. It was due to the DISPLAY not being set, so I placed it in the .Xdbus so that it exports each time that source is ran

Comment: Thanks for responding.  If you resolved the problem, you can help other people who have this problem in the future by posting the resolution as an answer.  Go into the ‘‘Your Answer’’ box (below) and describe what you did.  Basically, take your comment (above) and, ideally, add a little more detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Programs that manipulate the display
need to have the `DISPLAY` environment variable set
to tell them *which* display to use. 
This is typically true, in particular,
for commands whose names begin with `x`, such as `xrandr` and `xinput`. 
The `DISPLAY` variable is set appropriately automatically for shells
that are running on the terminal, but not for scripts triggered by events.

You’ll need to determine the name of the display that the ACPI events are for,
and set the `DISPLAY` environment variable accordingly.